# How to tell Angular2 to ignore an embedded Angular1 app?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I've got an Angular1 app bootstrapped inside an Angular2 component.

Template:

```
<div #ng1Hook></div>
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.filters.date" />
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('ng1Hook') div; 
ngAfterViewInit() {
    angular.bootstrap(this.div.nativeElement, ['ng1Module']);
}
```

The problem is that NG2 is trying to parse the NG1 code inside of its template. For example, further down the template there's code like this: `ng-model="vm.filters.date"` and ofcourse NG2 can't handle this.

Right now, my NG2 component is complaining it cannot read property `'xyz'` of undefined which is something I'm using in the NG1 component template  `ng-model=vm.xyz`

How can I tel NG2 to ignore the NG1 code inside of its template?
Or are there other ways of properly embedding NG1 inside NG2?

Comment: Angular2 wouldn't try to handle `ng-model="vm.filters.date"`. Can you please provide more details about what the problem is exactly?

Comment: Actually I doubt it's caused by `ng-model=vm.xyz`. This snippet doesn't contain anything that would Angular2 cause to process it. I rather think you have something like `{{vm.xyz}}` in your HTML which would be processed by Angular2.

Comment: I might be wrongly implementing ng1 inside ng2, basically I've got the full ng1 module inside the ng2 component, which might not be able to work at all. I do get logs from the ng1 module through though, so it's alive. I'm just looking to find the right place to put the ng1 module html

Comment: You might consider an iframe. There is also ngUpgrade/ngDowngrade in Angular2 to make Angular1 code work in Angular2 but I don't know Angular1 and haven't tried them myself.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html

Comment: I guess I'll have to look into an iframe, not the most elegant of solutions, but might get the job done. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the attribute `ngNonBindable` to prevent Angular2 to process bindings or instantiate directives or or components.

If the HTML is added dynamically Angular2 also won't process it

```
<div [innerHTML]="someHtml">
```

The content of `someHtml` would be added to the DOM and not processed by Angular2 in any way.